# Codeigniter redirect() function behaves wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed a basic application using codeigniter framework on wampserver on windows.
After I uploaded the application on the remote server which is a linux machine, I had to change many configurations to make the application work on the server. Most of them was due to wrong routing rules considerations and PHP version compatibility (like using of `__DIR__` constant which is not available in PHP versions lower than 5.3).

If I haven't logged in, the controller redirects to `users/login` route using the `redirect()` function.

But I have an strange problem when I want to access the app on my windows machine (localhost), the controller redirects to the remote version of the application (`www.remote.com/users/login` instead of `localhost/users/login`).
I have checked the `config/routes.php` file as well as `config/config.php` and value of the `$config['base_url']`, nothing is pointing to the remote site.

**UPDATE:**
this is the controller's constructor which redirects the user to login page if not logged in already:

```
public function __construct() {
    if(!isset($this->session->userdata["logged_in"]) || !$this->session->userdata["logged_in"]) {
        redirect("/users/login");
        exit();
    }
}
```

and this is the route for login:

```
$route['users/login'] = 'users/login';
```

and the config for `base_url`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.portal.com:8000/';
```

Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please show more of your code?
There must be thing pointing to your remote server, it might even be one line you are overlooking somewhere. Happened to me before.

**Update**

Try removing the `"/"` from `redirect("/users/login");` so then it would be

```
redirect("users/login");
```

**or** try removing the string from the base_url, so it would read:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

codeigniter should then automaticly pick up the base_url

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer,I think

Comment: I cant comment.. says I need 50 reputarion :/

Comment: please let know if you solved your problem and/or if you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

In your config file set base_url like this:

```
$baseUrl = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$baseUrl .= isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : getenv('HTTP_HOST');
$baseUrl .= isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) : dirname(getenv('SCRIPT_NAME'));

$config['base_url'] = $baseUrl;
```

this base_url works both localhost & remote server.

and then use

```
redirect("users/login");
```

without changing any route.

Answer (score 1):

use full path to redirect like that:

```
redirect($this->config->base_url()."/users/login");
```

you can also use dynamic $config['base_url']
replace localhost in config.php to this code

```
$config['host_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['host_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] = $config['host_url'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```